# How can I influence the spaces between labels on a BarChart

Tags: plotting

I want to chart data using a `BarChart`, the labels on the x-axis are numbers. Unfortunately they are so close to each other it really looks strange and more like one huge number. How can I add a spacing between the labels?

The relevant piece of code:

```
datalist = {{12, 1, 1}, {13, 0, 1}, {19, 3, 1}, {20, 5, 2}, {21, 5, 2}, 
{22, 1, 9}, {23, 18, 20}, {24, 3, 3}, {26, 1, 15}, {27, 12, 4}, {28, 8, 9}, 
{29, 4, 6}, {30, 3, 5}, {31, 2, 3}, {32, 0, 5}, {33, 7, 2}, {34, 14, 2},
{35, 1, 6}, {36, 1, 0}, {37, 3, 8}, {39, 1, 1}, {40, 1, 15}, {42, 3, 1},
{44, 1, 3}, {47, 12, 0}, {50, 9, 1}, {51, 0, 1}, {52, 0, 3}, {53, 1, 1},
{56, 1, 1}, {58, 12, 1}, {62, 3, 1}, {67, 1, 0}, {71, 5, 3}, {80, 1, 2}};

BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
    ChartLabels -> { Transpose[datalist][[1]], None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one approach, which modifies the labels slightly to shift some of the labels down a bit.

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {
      MapIndexed[If[OddQ[First[#2]], #, Column[{"", #}]] &, Transpose[datalist][[1]]], 
      None
      }]
```

[image]

Comment: That's clever. I never would have though of replacing every other label with `Column["", label]`, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer It assumes that the labels are sufficiently short.  Hopefully we'll get some more solutions. (I can think of at least two, in addition to an alternative way of doing what mine does.)

Comment: You're right about that assumption. An immediate alternative is rotating them `90 Degree`.

Comment: Posted it, low hanging fruit and all.

Answer (score 13):

Or Use ImageSize and BarSpacing

```
datalist = {{12, 1, 1}, {13, 0, 1}, {19, 3, 1}, {20, 5, 2}, {21, 5, 
   2}, {22, 1, 9}, {23, 18, 20}, {24, 3, 3}, {26, 1, 15}, {27, 12, 
   4}, {28, 8, 9}, {29, 4, 6}, {30, 3, 5}, {31, 2, 3}, {32, 0, 
   5}, {33, 7, 2}, {34, 14, 2}, {35, 1, 6}, {36, 1, 0}, {37, 3, 
   8}, {39, 1, 1}, {40, 1, 15}, {42, 3, 1}, {44, 1, 3}, {47, 12, 
   0}, {50, 9, 1}, {51, 0, 1}, {52, 0, 3}, {53, 1, 1}, {56, 1, 
   1}, {58, 12, 1}, {62, 3, 1}, {67, 1, 0}, {71, 5, 3}, {80, 1, 
   2}}; BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {Transpose[datalist][[1]], None}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[1], BarSpacing -> .5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

An alternative is to rotate the labels by 90 degrees:

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {
      Map[Rotate[Text[#], π/2] &, Transpose[datalist][[1]]],  
      None
   }
]
```

[image]

Or, if you prefer some extra spacing, here's another one which adapts [Brett's method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4414/52):

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]],
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   ChartLabels -> {
    MapIndexed[
     With[{rottext =  Rotate[Text[#], π/2], odd = OddQ[First@#2]},
        If[odd, rottext, Column[{"", rottext}]]
     ] &, 
     Transpose[datalist][[1]]
    ], 
    None
 }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Personally I prefer Brett's solution, but I wanted to show a few alternative ways to move the chart labels vertically so they are away from each other.

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[datalist[[All, 1]], Above], None}]
```

[image]

This version works much better if the labels are regularly spaced numbers. I prefer `AdjustmentBox` to `Column` because it allows more control.

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[datalist[[All, 1]], Axis, 
    DisplayForm@AdjustmentBox[#, BoxBaselineShift -> 2 Mod[#, 3]] &], 
   None}]
```

[image]

Depending on your operating system and font, you can get some help from the `FontTracking` option:

```
BarChart[datalist[[All, {2, 3}]], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[datalist[[All, 1]], Axis, 
    Style[#, FontTracking -> "Narrow"] &], None}]
```

[image]