# How can I avoid label collisions?

Tags: plotting, visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I influence the spaces between labels on a BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/how-can-i-influence-the-spaces-between-labels-on-a-barchart)

How can I avoid label collisions in plot ticks and labels? For example, here is a histogram with colliding frame tick labels:

```
BarChart[{Labeled[{196}, Row[{"Jan", "Feb 23"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{349}, Row[{"Feb 23", "Apr 15"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{333}, Row[{"Apr 15", "Jun 6"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{308}, Row[{"Jun 6", "Jul 28"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{308}, Row[{"Jul 28", "Sep 19"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{344}, Row[{"Sep 19", "Nov 10"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{162}, Row[{"Nov 10", "Jan"}, "-"], Below]}, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Bitstream Charter", 10], 
 BarSpacing -> 0, Ticks -> None, GridLines -> None, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BarOrigin -> Bottom, BarSpacing -> None, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartStyle -> {Directive[
    EdgeForm[{Opacity[1.`], Thickness[Medium], Blue}], Opacity[1.`], 
    FaceForm[LightBlue]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the question has two parts:

1. How to detect collisions in frame tick labels in general.
2. How to rearrange labels to minimize collisions and optimize for aesthetics.

I'm not sure how to do part 1, but part 2 should involve either rotations or columns I guess. I would rather not assume a specific font or size of text, but perhaps this is unavoidable.

Comment: I do not see the example histogram.

Comment: Weird, I can't upload images. The toolbar is gone! What should I do? I've tried restarting safari.

Comment: Stay with us. Don't look down. Breath slowly and deep-

Comment: You could use [Szabolcs' picture upload tool](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/57) to directly upload graphics from Mathematica to StackExchange.

Comment: Ok, I did, but my code still isn't code.

Comment: Take a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/how-to-align-rotated-tick-labels  More generally, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=labels

Comment: Also dup of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/how-to-rotate-tickmarks-in-datelistplot

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the labels like this:

```
rot[x_] := Rotate[x, \[Pi]/2]

BarChart[{Labeled[{196}, rot@Row[{"Jan", "Feb 23"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{349}, rot@Row[{"Feb 23", "Apr 15"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{333}, rot@Row[{"Apr 15", "Jun 6"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{308}, rot@Row[{"Jun 6", "Jul 28"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{308}, rot@Row[{"Jul 28", "Sep 19"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{344}, rot@Row[{"Sep 19", "Nov 10"}, "-"], Below], 
  Labeled[{162}, rot@Row[{"Nov 10", "Jan"}, "-"], Below]}, 
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Bitstream Charter", 10], 
 BarSpacing -> 0, Ticks -> None, GridLines -> None, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BarOrigin -> Bottom, BarSpacing -> None, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartStyle -> {Directive[
    EdgeForm[{Opacity[1.`], Thickness[Medium], Blue}], Opacity[1.`], 
    FaceForm[LightBlue]]}]
```

[image: Example barchart with rotated labels]